# mysql - FLUSH TABLE needed?

Tags: mysql, optimization, repair

After I `REPAIR` `OPTIMIZE` `ANALYZE` OR `CHECK` a table, do I need to `FLUSH` it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A flush is not necessary.

When it comes to [**ANALYZE TABLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/analyze-table.html) or [**CHECK TABLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/check-table.html), they just read the table. `ANALYZE` will write index statistics elsewhere.

When it comes to [**REPAIR TABLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/repair-table.html) or [**OPTIMIZE TABLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html), they perform full DDL by copying the MyISAM table to a temp table and then renaming the table back.